# Can I modify a rigify rig to add a head after generating it?

Tags: rigging, rigify

So a while back I rigged a model using rigify in blender 2.8, and deleted the face bones, as it was way too complex for what I wanted to do with the character. Flashback to now, and I've spent hours making animations for the model, but would now like to add facial animations to go along with the body one's I made. Is there anything I can do to add a face rig, because it doesen't seem like I can modify the rig in edit mode, the new bones I make do nothing? I'm ok with rigging a new character but I would like to be able to save the animations I made with this rig? Thanks so much I would apricate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/rigging/rigify.html

From the manual:
Nondisruptive re-rig
If the generated rig doesn’t fit all the features you need or, for example, you decide to add something more to your character (like a sixth arm or a tail), you can re-generate your rig without losing your previously generated features and your animation data.

Comment: Thank you! This worked great!