# Joining facebuilder head to downloaded body

Tags: mesh, rigify

So I am a complete beginner to 3D modelling and animation. Just wanted to experiment some in my free time. Not looking for a career in this. I built a head model using facebuilder. and downloaded a character model from the internet, removed the head from the body, and have been trying to make one model out of the two, since rigify doesn't work for separate head and body. I have tried bool tool union with no result or very bad result, grabbing and merging vertices but even then its not one single model and rigify doesn't work as expected. Ctrl+j and then remesh removes all the textures and the model is unusable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zvjI.jpg In this image, you can see the head and body I am working with.

My aim is simple, build a head using facebuilder(or any addon you can suggest) and attach it to a generic body, so that I can then rig it  for a short animation. Sorry if this has been answered before, but I couldn't find any tutorial specific for joining facebuilder head to a body. Thanks in advance for any suggestion you can provide. If there's another addon like rigify which can work on separate head and body, please let me know.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: It's possible to have a single rig (or armature) with multiple objects or with a single object consisting of multiple meshes. Most important is that you parent these things to the armature. The influence of the vertex weights (and how they are set up) will determine if the (possibly fragmented) character moves as one. I don't think it's easy, but also not very hard if you check some of the basics of rigging in general (apart form using Rigify) Also [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187309/can-i-modify-a-rigify-rig-to-add-a-head-after-generating-it?rq=1) might help